# JSoup - Extracting table data error

Tags: java, html, arrays, parsing, jsoup

I've just began a small project of which I will need to gather historical data on global currency pairs. Following a answer from this question [Extract Data out of table with JSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13545658/extract-data-out-of-table-with-jsoup), I have the code pasted below.

However I keep receiving an `IndexOutOfBoundException`, although the 'data' Elements array is of size 7?

I've been scratching my head for almost an hour, and would appreciate if someone could point out where I have gone wrong!

**Main Class**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.*;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;


public class MainClass {


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.myfxbook.com/forex-market/currencies/GBPUSD-historical-data").get();

    Element table = doc.getElementById("symbolMarket");

    List<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<Entry>();

    for(Element row : table.select("tr")){

        int index = 0;
        Entry tableEntry = new Entry();
        Elements data = row.select("td");

        tableEntry.setDate(data.get(index++).text());
        tableEntry.setOpen(data.get(index++).text());
        tableEntry.setHigh(data.get(index++).text());
        tableEntry.setLow(data.get(index++).text());
        tableEntry.setClose(data.get(index++).text());
        tableEntry.setChangePips(data.get(index++).text());
        tableEntry.setChangePercent(data.get(index++).text());

        entries.add(tableEntry);

    }

}

}
```

**Entries Class**

```
public class Entry {

private String date;
private String open;
private String high;
private String low;
private String close;
private String changePips;
private String changePercent;

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}
public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}
public String getOpen() {
    return open;
}
public void setOpen(String open) {
    this.open = open;
}
public String getHigh() {
    return high;
}
public void setHigh(String high) {
    this.high = high;
}
public String getLow() {
    return low;
}
public void setLow(String low) {
    this.low = low;
}
public String getClose() {
    return close;
}
public void setClose(String close) {
    this.close = close;
}
public String getChangePips() {
    return changePips;
}
public void setChangePips(String changePips) {
    this.changePips = changePips;
}
public String getChangePercent() {
    return changePercent;
}
public void setChangePercent(String changePercent) {
    this.changePercent = changePercent;
}



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get the data from the table header... you have to skip it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.myfxbook.com/forex-market/currencies/GBPUSD-historical-data").get();

        Element table = doc.getElementById("symbolMarket");

        List<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<Entry>();

        Elements elements = table.select("tr");
        Iterator<Element> itr = elements.iterator();
        itr.next(); //skip header data

        while ( itr.hasNext() ) {
            int index = 0;
            Entry tableEntry = new Entry();
            Elements data = itr.next().select("td");

            tableEntry.setDate(data.get(index++).text());
            tableEntry.setOpen(data.get(index++).text());
            tableEntry.setHigh(data.get(index++).text());
            tableEntry.setLow(data.get(index++).text());
            tableEntry.setClose(data.get(index++).text());
            tableEntry.setChangePips(data.get(index++).text());
            tableEntry.setChangePercent(data.get(index++).text());
            entries.add(tableEntry);

        }       




    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> However I keep receiving an `IndexOutOfBoundException`, although the 'data' Elements array is of size 7?

If that would be true you wouldn't see this exception.

Problem is that first row doesn't have any `td`, but `th` (table headers), so for this row `row.select("td")` has `0` elements which matches `td` selector, and you are informed about it by info from exception

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

To solve this problem you can simply ignore first row, or explicitly pick `tr` which `has` at least one `td` as child element

```
for(Element row : table.select("tr:has(td)")){
    //                            ^^^^^^^^
    ...
}
```

You can also manually test size of `data` storing `td` before you apply any action to it

```
for(Element row : table.select("tr")){
    Elements data = row.select("td");

    if(data.size()==7){

        int index = 0;
        Entry tableEntry = new Entry();

        tableEntry.setDate(data.get(index++).text());
        tableEntry.setOpen(data.get(index++).text());
        tableEntry.setHigh(data.get(index++).text());
        tableEntry.setLow(data.get(index++).text());
        tableEntry.setClose(data.get(index++).text());
        tableEntry.setChangePips(data.get(index++).text());
        tableEntry.setChangePercent(data.get(index++).text());

        entries.add(tableEntry);
    }
}
```