# Parsing table html with Jsoup

Tags: java, html, json, parsing, jsoup

I'm try to parsing this table:

```
    <table border="1" align="center" cellpadding="5" width="95%">  
 <tbody> 
  <tr> 
   <td colspan="2" align="center"> <b> <i> Test </i> </b> </td> 
   <td> <b> <i> Result </i> </b> </td> 
   <td> <b> <i> Credit </i> </b> </td> 
   <td> <b> <i> Data </i> </b> </td> 
   <td> <b> <i> A/A </i> </b> </td> 
   <td> <b> <i> Other data </i> </b> </td> 
   <td> <b> <i> A/A rif. </i> </b> </td> 
  </tr> 
  <tr> 
   <td> A000211 </td> 
   <td nowrap=""> Physic </td> 
   <td align="center"> - </td> 
   <td align="center"> 6 </td> 
   <td align="center"> - </td> 
   <td align="center"> 2008/2009 </td> 
   <td> something </td> 
   <td align="center"> 2007/2008 </td> 
  </tr> 
  <tr> 
   <td> 0065057 </td> 
   <td nowrap=""> Math </td> 
   <td align="center"> - </td> 
   <td align="center"> 6 </td> 
   <td align="center"> - </td> 
   <td align="center"> 2008/2009 </td> 
   <td> samething </td> 
   <td align="center"> 2008/2009 </td> 
  </tr> 
  <tr>
```

In java i have this, for now:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(url);


Elements tables = doc.getElementsByTag("table");
```

I try to put this data in JsonObject i must iterate this tables? or there is a simple way?

Comment: possibly duplicated with [Using JSoup To Extract HTML Table Contents][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8222118/using-jsoup-to-extract-html-table-contents

Comment: possibly duplicated with [Using JSoup To Extract HTML Table Contents][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8222118/using-jsoup-to-extract-html-table-contents

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i solved with:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(url);
       JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
       JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
       Element rows = doc.getElementsByTag("table tr");

      for(Element row : rows) {
          String Test = row.getElementsByTag("td").get(1).text();
          String Result = row.getElementsByTag("td").get(2).text();
          String Credit = row.getElementsByTag("td").get(3).text();

          jsonObject.put("Test", Test); 
          jsonObject.put("Result", Result);
          jsonObject.put("Credit", Credit); 
      }
```