# Structure JSOUP content to JSON

Tags: java, json, jsoup

I extract some data from a http site and now I want to format this using JSON . I watched some examples but i don't understand how to do that exactly .I want something like that :

```
{  
  Product name:"Samsung..."
    { review 1:"..."
      review 2:"..."
   }
}
```

Also my code don't iterate over all reviews, it stops at page 1 ,and there is 10 more pages and i want to get like 20-30 reviews at least. There is what i did until now :

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class JsoupMain {

private static int nr = 1;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Document document = null;
    try {
        document = Jsoup.connect("http://www.emag.ro/telefon-mobil-samsung- galaxy-j5-2016-dual-sim-16gb-4g-gold-sm-j510fzdurom/pd/DQD3B7BBM/").get();

        String title = document.title();
        System.out.println("Title: " + title);

        Elements review = document.select("div.product-review-body");

        for (Element rev : review) {
            System.out.println("Review : " + nr + " :" + rev.text() + "\n");
            nr++;
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

See this answer for a similar question - [Parsing table html with Jsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20573728/parsing-table-html-with-jsoup) In your case it might look like this:

```
    JSONObject root = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray reviews = new JSONArray();
    root.put("name", "Product Name");
    for (int i=0; i < elements.size(); i++){
        JSONObject review = new JSONObject();
        review.put("review"+i , elements.get(i).text());
        reviews.add(review);
    }
    root.put("reviews", reviews);
```

The JSON output for root would look like this:

```
{
   "name":"Product Name",
   "reviews":[
      {
         "review0":"ok"
      },
      {
         "review1":"awesome"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: The method add is not defined for JSONArray ,that's what eclipse say

Comment: What version of 'json-lib' are you using? The above code was based on this dependency - "net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:2.4:jdk15" .

Comment: I resolved the problem in that time,but it still don't show info's like i want . I mean reviews to be one under one another. I will atach you my code..but i don't know what verios of JSON library i use and to be honest I don't know where to found that

Comment: Instead of using JSONArray simply put JSONObjects in your main JSONObject. Note that your desired format example is invalid JSON. Checkout rules on valid format at http://www.json.org/

Comment: I see that can be converted in some pretty print JSON array but i don't get how it works

Answer (score 0):

I want to make this code to show info exactly like that:

```
 { Reviews:
   {  review 1: "..."}
   {  review 2: "..."}
     ................
     ................
 }
```

In present my code is printing info's like that: "Reviews":[[{"Review 0":"Foarte multumit Un telefon foarte bun. Ce m-a impresionat este camera foto care face niste poze foarte bune"},{"R............}

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class JsoupMain {

private static int nr = 1;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Document document = null;
    try {
        document = Jsoup.connect("http://www.emag.ro/telefon-mobil-samsung-galaxy-j5-2016-dual-sim-16gb-4g-gold-sm-j510fzdurom/pd/DQD3B7BBM/").get();

        String title = document.title();
        System.out.println("Product name : " + title);

        Elements review = document.select("div.product-review-body");

        JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject root = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
        root.put("Product name", title);
        for (int i = 0; i < review.size(); i++) {
            JSONObject revieww = new JSONObject();
            revieww.put("Review " + i, review.get(i).text());
            list.put(revieww);

        }

        mainObject.accumulate("Reviews", list);
        System.out.println(mainObject);

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code from  `Elements review = document.select("div.product-review-body");...` to   `... System.out.println(mainObject);` with the following code snippet.

```
            Elements review = document.select("div[class=product-review-body]");
            JSONObject parent = new JSONObject();
            parent.put("Product name", title);
            JSONArray reviews = new JSONArray();
            int i = 1;
            for (Element rev : review) {
                reviews.put(new JSONObject().put("review" + i, rev.text()));
                i++;
            }
            parent.put("Reviews", reviews);
            System.out.println(parent);
```

Hope this helps.